# Link jade and javascript files

Tags: javascript, express, client, client-server, pug

I'm starting with Express and I have already a problem in my first program. Below is the code I'm using. Layout.jade

```
doctype html
html
  head
    title= title
    link(rel='stylesheet', href='/stylesheets/style.css')
  body
    block content
    script(type='type/javascript', src='./public/javascripts/temperature.js')
```

index.jade:

```
extends layout
block content
  h1= title
  p Welcome to #{title}
  input#textBox(type='text', name='textBox') 
  input#myButton(type='button', value='Random Temperature!', name='myButton', onclick='click()')
```

temperature.js:

```
const textBox = document.getElementById('tb');
const button = document.getElementById('myButton');
function click(){
    var rnd = Math.floor(Math.random() * 100);
    textBox.value = rnd;
};
```

When I run the application I'm able to see in the browser the text box and the button but when I click on the button nothing happens. I guess my problem is the linking between the 3 files but I tried several things and I can't solve the problem. I'm sure it's a stupid error but forgive me I'm just getting start. Any advice?

Comment: It must be `const textBox = document.getElementById('textBox');` instead of `tb`

Comment: Thank you very much but it's not that

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1 and 2. Change:

```
    script(type='type/javascript', src='./public/javascripts/temperature.js')
```

to

```
    script(type='type/javascript', src='/javascripts/temperature.js')
```

since `./` for relative path, and `/` is for root path + you shouldn't include `public` in path.

3. make sure you have your `js` file in public folder and served `public folder` as `static folder` in express with:

```
app.use(express.static(__dirname + '/public'))
```

Also there is couple more issues:

4. change `document.getElementById('tb')` to `document.getElementById('textBox')`
5. change `script(type='type/javascript', ...)` to `script(type='text/javascript', ...)`
6. change `onclick='click()'` to `onclick='onclicked()'` and `function click(){` to `function onclicked(){` because i think click is reserved keyword in JavaScript.
7. rename `Layout.jade` to `layout.jade` since you extend `layout` not `Layout`
   Here is the project.

You can see the project here: https://codesandbox.io/s/nodejs-jade-js-kq945

(note that in this project,the index.js is in src folder, so static folder is `path.join(__dirname, "../public")` , not `path.join(__dirname, "/public")`. also you can run it online, fork it to edit it online, or download it from file -> export to zip.)

---

Edit: Here is my debugging process:

1. first i checked the network tab, it didn't load js file. (there wasnt any error, actually there wasn't any request to get js file)
2. i hit cntrl+u to check source code, and clicked on .js link, and it get me error '404 not found', so i found address is wrong, and i found out i should changed '/public/js/...' to '/js/...'.
3. even now, there isn't any request for js file in network tab, so i changed : `<script type='type/javascript'` to `<script type='text/javascript'`
4. now js file is loaded in network tab, but the click function didn't work. i wrote `click` in console tab, and it gives me the function. so the `click` function is defined, but `onlick='click()'` not works. after some minutes, i guessed its problem with `click` word, so i renamed it.

Comment: Thank you very much, in express I have: app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'public'))); it was automatically generated. My problem continues

Comment: @Raphael see chrome dev tools -> network tab , to check if js file is loaded without error. and also add a `console.log('aa')` at start of your js file to check if js works.

Comment: Thanks for the help! I believe the js file is not loaded but the 'aa' appears in the console... I don't get it it should be this easy

Comment: @Raphael Np, so js is loaded, did you change `document.getElementById('tb')` to `document.getElementById('textBox')` as well ?

Comment: Yes, I have. Should I add something in the express regarding the js file?

Comment: @Raphael No, linking to js file is as easy as putting js in a static public directory(like 'public/js') and linking to it with absolute path (like : '/public/js/script1.js'). So did your script work?

Comment: Still not working... I put the js file in the same folder to facilitate. And 'aa' didn't show up actually. In the dev tools I see the html generated and it seems right but when I try to open the temperature.js it sends "Not Found
404". Ddefinitely the script isn't load. Thanks a lot for your time trying to help me!!

Comment: @Raphael no problem. i'll check your code in an express app and see if it works for me, shortly.

Comment: @Raphael did it. i can't beleive there was 3 more problems :p i'll update the answer. tell me if you want me to upload the project files as well.

Comment: @Raphael i updated the answer, read it carefully, specially 1 and 2, make sure not include `public` in path. src='/javascripts/...'), not src='/public/javascripts/...'),

Comment: @Raphael I added debugging process in answer. glad it helped, You're welcome :)